# Run multiple semicolon separated query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert

Is there any way where i can run Multiple semicolon separated query in Code Igniter without `insert_batch()` ?

e.g:

```
$a = 'INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3); INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3);';
$this->db->query($a);
```

**Above code gives `invalid query` error.**

Comment: no library in php executes more than one query

Comment: @splash58 Excecpt for `mysqli_multi_query()`, of course.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks. I missed it

Comment: @splash58 You haven't missed much. IMHO, it's rarely useful, and it's a pain to use.

Answer (score 3):

### If multiple tables with single data(Using [Transactions](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#transactions)) - (N table vs 1 Data)

[**Running Transactions Manually**](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions-manually)

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)');
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3)');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

[**Running Transactions Automatically**](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions)

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)');
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3)');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

---

### If inserting Single table with multiple data (1 table vs N Data)

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'a' => 'My title 1' ,
      'b' => 'My Name 1' ,
      'c' => 'My date 1'
   ),
   array(
      'a' => 'My title 2' ,
      'b' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'c' => 'My date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```